# cx-oracle-executemany()-batch-insert-error-expecting-number

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, executemany

I have a list

bind_insert:

```
    [(3, 18, '01-10-2021', 'M51078', 'AABCM5192K', '01280', 'AABCM5192K', None, None, 'X95091', 'AZEPK0300N', 
'C', 'CO', 'N01477', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 'N', 
'N', 'Y', '05-10-2021', 'SYSTEM', None, None), (4, 18, '01-10-2021', 'M51078', 'AABCM5192K', '01280', 'AABCM5192K', None, None, 'LP1059', 'ASCPC7149Q', 'C', 'CO', 'TEST2', 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 
123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 123000000.0, 'N', 'N', 'Y', '05-10-2021', 'SYSTEM', None, None), (5, 18, '01-10-2021', None, 'AABCM5192K', None, None, 'ILFSLOU01', 'AAACL7361E', None, 'AAACG7034K', 'C', 'CO', 'N01582', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 'N', 'N', 'Y', '05-10-2021', 'SYSTEM', None, None), (6, 18, '01-10-2021', None, 'AABCM5192K', None, None, 'ILFSSHA01', 'AABCS3644N', None, 'ADPPA5335E', 'C', 'CO', 'N01490', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 'N', 'N', 'Y', '05-10-2021', 'SYSTEM', None, None)]
```

When list contains only one tuple it inserts successfully into DB I tried with all individual tuple in bind_insert but when all 3 tuples are present it gives Expecting number error in executemany()

My Code:

```
for b in bind_insert :
for index, value in enumerate(b):
        if isinstance(value, float) and math.isnan(value):
            b[index] = None
        elif isinstance(value, type(pd.NaT)):
            b[index] = None
print("before")
                       
                  
start_time = time.time()                  
                                                     
                                
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
cursor.executemany("insert into "+config.NcsOwner+".COLL_CLIENT_SUBMISSION_DTLS values (:1,:2,to_date(:3,'DD-MM-YYYY'),:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22,:23,:24,:25,:26,:27,:28,:29,:30,:31,:32,:33,:34,:35,:36,:37,:38,:39,:40,:41,:42,:43,:44,:45,:46,:47,:48,:49,:50,:51,:52,:53,:54,:55,:56,:57,:58,:59,to_date(:60,'DD-MM-YYYY'),:61,to_date(:62,'DD-MM-YYYY'),:63)", bind_insert)
                                     
                                                                 
connection.commit()
```

**Error:**

```
    Exception has occurred: TypeError
expecting number
  File "D:\Alok\CR06645_PythonCode\insertdf.py", line 42, in InsertIntoDB
    cursor.executemany("insert into "+config.NcsOwner+".COLL_CLIENT_SUBMISSION_DTLS values (:1,:2,to_date(:3,'DD-MM-YYYY'),:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22,:23,:24,:25,:26,:27,:28,:29,:30,:31,:32,:33,:34,:35,:36,:37,:38,:39,:40,:41,:42,:43,:44,:45,:46,:47,:48,:49,:50,:51,:52,:53,:54,:55,:56,:57,:58,:59,to_date(:60,'DD-MM-YYYY'),:61,to_date(:62,'DD-MM-YYYY'),:63)", bind_insert)
  File "D:\Alok\CR06645_PythonCode\CR6645script.py", line 1073, in CollateralValidation
    bVal=insertdf.InsertIntoDB(FinalDataframe,fileCSVName)
  File "D:\Alok\CR06645_PythonCode\CR6645script.py", line 34, in readCSV
    abc=CollateralValidation(dfFileNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer using

- `date` type of `datetime` module instead of `TO_DATE` conversion of DB layer
- Parametrized query string rather than concatenated one(*it's securer principally*)
- A loop in order to get a `bind_insert` list(`:1, :2, :3, ... :63`) dynamically, rather than explicitly writing them through use of the first element o the tuple(`bind_insert[0]`)

such as

```py
 bind_insert=[    
             (3,18,'TEST1',datetime.date(2021,10,1),'M51078'...),
             (4,18,'TEST2',datetime.date(2021,10,1),'M51078'...),
             .....
 ]
 
 val=""
 j=0
 for i in bind_insert[0]:
     j+=1
     val+=':'.join(' '+str(j)) + ','
     values=val.rstrip(",")
     
 table = config.NcsOwner+".coll_client_submission_dtls"
     
 my_query = f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES({values})"
 
 cursor.executemany(my_query,bind_insert)
```